# transfer a drop-down menu from one tab to another with google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I am currently developing a code on a Sheet that has several tabs.
The goal is, thanks to Google Script, to transfer lines from one tab to another according to the selected state (idea, specifications, in development, transferred, completed, closed and cancelled).
The first tab contains all the unprocessed ideas with different information to indicate. Some of this information is available in drop-down menus.

[Screenshot of the tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT3DG.png)

What I want is that when I change the status of the idea and run my function, this line is transferred to the corresponding tab.

All this works perfectly with the code below:

```
function transfertDemandes(){

  // Déclaration du fichier Sheet et des différents onglets
  const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const feuilleIdees = classeur.getSheetByName("Non traité");
  const feuilleDeveloppement = classeur.getSheetByName("En développement");
  const feuilleTermine = classeur.getSheetByName("Terminé");
  const feuilleArchive = classeur.getSheetByName("Archivé");
  const feuilleTransfere = classeur.getSheetByName("Transféré");
  const feuilleAnnule = classeur.getSheetByName("Annulé");

  // ------ TRANSFERT DES IDÉES ------ //

  // Connaissance du nombre d'idées référencées dans l'onglet
  var lignesIdees = feuilleIdees.getRange("A3:A").getValues();
  var nbLignesIdees = lignesIdees.filter(String).length;

  for (let i = 0; i<nbLignesIdees; i ++){

  // Création des coordonnées pour les idées
    var rowIdees = 3 + i;
    var rangeEtat = "C" + (3 + i);

    // Récupération de la dernière ligne du fichier Développement
    var derniereLigneDev = feuilleDeveloppement.getLastRow(); 
    var rowCollageDev = derniereLigneDev + 1;

    var tIdees = feuilleIdees.getRange(rowIdees,1, 1, 12).getValues();

    // Récupération de l'état et traitement selon les informations renseignées
    var etatIdee = feuilleIdees.getRange(rangeEtat).getValue(); 
    if (etatIdee === "Idée"){
      continue;
    } else if (etatIdee === "Cahier des Charges") {
      Logger.log(tIdees);
      feuilleDeveloppement.getRange(rowCollageDev,1,1,12).setValues(tIdees);
      Logger.log ("à transférer dans En développement");
    } else if (etatIdee === "En développement") {
      Logger.log ("à transférer dans En développement");
    } else if (etatIdee === "Terminé") {
      Logger.log ("à transférer dans Terminé");
    } else if (etatIdee === "Clôturé") {
      Logger.log ("à transférer dans Clôturé");
    } else if (etatIdee === "Annulé") {
    Logger.log ("à transférer dans Annulé");
    } else if (etatIdee === "Transféré") {
      Logger.log ("à transférer dans Transféré");
    } else {
      Logger.log("erreur");
    }
  }
}
```

However, it only copies the strings and does not take into account the dropdown menus. However, I would like it to paste in the new tab the dropdown menu as well so that I can repeat the operation for each step (and therefore for each tab).

[Here is a screenshot of what I get in the "In development" tab after running the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxwEg.png)

Would you have an idea?

I also take advantage of this message to know if you know a way to keep 'the layout' (centered text, bold, ...) when copying?

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: This is an instance where it is better to SHOW than to try to TELL. I encourage you to set up a sample spreadsheet with realistic data filling 5 or 10 rows. Manually enter into that sheet what the expected results would be, placed in the exact range where you'd like a formula to produce those results. Be sure, when you create the link, to set the permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor" so that those here can access the sheet, test approaches, and leave any solutions for you.

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is to copy the master sheet (empty sheet but with all formatted cells, drop down menus etc.) to other sheets (change the color of the first rows if you want). Then only use copy as values, for instance :

```
  archive.insertRowBefore(2);
  var plage = origine.getRange('A' + cel.getRow() + ':K' + cel.getRow());
  plage.copyTo(archive.getRange('A' + 2), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

You can do it with an onEdit function